# ORACLE Natural Join returns empty results "no rows selected" have same columns both tables

Tags: sql, oracle, natural-join

HELLO my main goal is to take x tables and join them w/o getting duplicates Columns which is used to detect the rows for the join operation. 
So i found that natural join is what i have looking for :

NOT wanted result with inner join :

http://s11.postimg.org/ujtadadj7/image.png

Good result with natural join :

http://s28.postimg.org/yy6tmca0d/image.png

The problem is that when i try to do the same with other table(not users) 
I get zero results ):

```
select * from guilds natural join players;
```

Where guilds table has guild_id and players has guild_id.

Why is it happens ? 
How should i accomplish my goal is there is another way?
Please help me , I were looking for solution all day . . .
Thanks for everyone who will try to help !

Comment: Please provide guilds and players schema with constraints.

Comment: please : http://s11.postimg.org/8jw8idm9v/image.png

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Comment: It might be a blind guess, but I see that data type differs in both tables `number` vs `number(4,0)`. Does the `INNER JOIN` not work for you? You could always list your columns explicitly, not using the asterisk sign.

Comment: a_horse_with_no_name : This is not image of code, this is icons that shows who is primary and who have constrain with other tables , instead of copying 1000 rows here is UI small image that explains all  .

Comment: Consider Me : thanks you very much ill check the numbers things, the explicitly option is not good here because i have to do it dynamically with 8 tables , i want to use only tables names .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do a `NATURAL JOIN`, your join will be done on every column that is common to the joined tables; so, if you have more than one column with the same name they will all be used in join. This can be why you don't have rows in your result.

`INNER JOIN` can be done as you did, with something like `ON (tab1.field = tab2.field)` or with the `USING` clause, without repeating the fields;

```
SQL> select *
  2  from dual
  3  natural join dual;

DUMMY
----------
X

SQL> select *
  2  from dual d1
  3  inner join dual d2 on (d1.dummy = d2.dummy);

DUMMY      DUMMY
---------- ----------
X          X

SQL> select *
  2  from dual d1
  3  inner join dual d2 using(dummy);

DUMMY
----------
X
```

Comment: Thanks amazing WOW its worked for any x tables with the using clause ! 3 tables : select *
from(
select *
from users inner join players using(user_id)
) inner join guilds using(guild_id)
where user_id=3;